# StreamingQueryListner spark structered Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working on structured streaming application wherein I'm reading from Kafka as stream and for each batch of streams I need to perform S3 lookup file (which is nearly 200gb) to fetch some attributes.

So I'm using df.persist() (basically caching the lookup) but I need to refresh the dataframe as the S3 lookup data changes frequently. I'm using below code

```scala
class RefreshcachedDF(sparkSession: SparkSession) extends StreamingQueryListener {

    override def onQueryStarted(event: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {}
    override def onQueryTerminated(event: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {}

    override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
       val currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
       if (currTime > (latestrefreshtime mentioned in a globaltempview)) {
          //oldDF is a cached Dataframe created from GlobalTempView which is of size 200GB.
          oldDF.unpersist() //I guess this is async call ,should i use unpersist(true) which is blocking?and is it safe ?
          val inputDf: DataFrame = readFile(spec, sparkSession)
          val recreateddf = inputDf.persist()
          val count = recreateddf.count()
          }

      }
    }
  }
```

Is the above approach is a better solution to refresh cached dataframe? and the trigger for this refresh is will store the expirydate of cache for S3 in a globaltempview .

- So the question is this the right place to refresh the cached df ?
- if yes should I use blocking or non-blocking unpersist method as the data is huge 200GB?
- For similar issue I see a response from Databricks committer giving below response

> Yes, you will have to recreate the streaming Dataframe along with the
>       static Dataframe, and restart the query. There isnt a currently feasible to
>       do this without a query restart. But restarting a query WITHOUT restarting
>       the whole application + spark cluster, is reasonably fast. If your
>       applicatoin can tolerate 10 second latencies, then stopping and restarting
>       a query within the same Spark application is a reasonable solution.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201705.mbox/browser

Subject : Refreshing a persisted RDD

So if that's better solution should I restart query as below

```scala
query.processAllavaialble()
query.stop()
df.unpersist()
val inputDf: DataFrame = readFile(spec, sparkSession) //read file from S3
or anyother source
val recreateddf = inputDf.persist()
//Start the query
```

When I looked into spark documentation of above methods

> ```
> void processAllAvailable() ///documentation says This method is intended
> ```
>
> for testing///
>
> Blocks until all available data in the source has been processed and
>   committed to the sink. This method is intended for testing. Note that in
>   the case of continually arriving data, this method may block forever.
>   Additionally, this method is only guaranteed to block until data that has
>   been synchronously appended data to a Source prior to invocation. (i.e.
>   `getOffset` must immediately reflect the addition).

> ```
> stop()
> ```
>
> Stops the execution of this query if it is running. This method blocks
>   until the threads performing execution has stopped.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQuery.html#processAllAvailable()

Please suggest a better approach to refresh the cache.